# Why doesn't this XSLT code return anything?

Tags: html, xml, templates, xslt

This is my XML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="2.xsl"?>

<xml_tube>
 <utilizadores>
  <utilizador username="Guicky" password="futurama96">
   <nome>Guilherme Luís</nome>
   <birthday>1996-11-28</birthday>
   <foto href="guilhas.jpg"/>
  </utilizador>
  <utilizador username="Daisy" password="woofwoof11">
   <nome>Daisy Luís</nome>
   <birthday>2011-04-04</birthday>
   <foto href="daisy.png"/>
  </utilizador>
  <utilizador username="Anabela65" password="crumble65">
   <nome>Anabela Ribeiro</nome>
   <birthday>1965-04-02</birthday>
   <foto href="belinha.jpg"/>
  </utilizador>
  <utilizador username="Izzie" password="lagartixa">
   <nome>Isadora Luís</nome>
   <birthday>1988-06-27</birthday>
   <foto href="izzie.jpg"/>
  </utilizador>
 </utilizadores>
 <videos_pub>
  <video id="Vid1" publisher="Daisy" duracao="3:37" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>Who let the dogs out? - Baha Men</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Qkuu0Lwb5EM/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>My favorite song, lol.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qkuu0Lwb5EM</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
   <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
   <likes liked="Guicky"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video id="Vid2" publisher="Guicky" duracao="4:01" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>Desiigner - Timmy Turner</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/JzmRt2VgKYQ/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>Timmy Timmy Timmy Turner.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/ProbPpO_8oo</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
   <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
   <likes liked="Daisy"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video id="Vid3" publisher="Guicky" duracao="3:47" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>I'm all the way up - Fat Joe</título>
   <thumb>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2ak_oBeC-I</thumb>
   <descrição>Nothing can stop me, I'm all the way up.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/y2ak_oBeC-I</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video id="Vid4" publisher="Anabela65" duracao="3:21" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>Putzgrilla - Sentadinha</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/QC4JbIvIhdI/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>Dá uma sentadinha.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC4JbIvIhdI</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <likes liked="Guicky"/>
   <likes liked="Daisy"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video data="2017-01-13" duracao="02:16" id="Vid5" publisher="Izzie">
   <título>Yann Tiersen - La Valse d'Amelie</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uzurqBnALkw/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>A minha música preferida.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzurqBnALkw</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <likes liked="Guicky"/>
   <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
 </videos_pub>
 <playlist>
  <lista owner="Guicky" dataIns="2016-10-24" id="PV1">
   <titulo>BEST MUSIC.</titulo>
   <descricao>Compilation of my favourite music videos.</descricao>
   <gostosL gostouL="Guicky"/>
   <links_vid vid="Vid2"/>
   <links_vid vid="Vid3"/>
   <administradores>
    <admin ref="Guicky"/>
    <admin ref="Daisy"/>
   </administradores>
   <editores>
    <editor ref="Guicky"/>
   </editores>
   <subscritores>
    <subs ref="Daisy"/>
    <subs ref="Anabela65"/>
   </subscritores>
   <thumbnail link="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/QC4JbIvIhdI/hqdefault.jpg"/>
  </lista>
  <lista owner="Anabela65" dataIns="2016-02-29" id="PV2">
   <titulo>Sentadinha!</titulo>
   <descricao>Siting lesson's with Guicky's mom!</descricao>
   <links_vid vid="Vid4"/>
   <administradores>
    <admin ref="Anabela65"/>
    <admin ref="Guicky"/>
   </administradores>
   <editores>
    <editor ref="Anabela65"/>
   </editores>
   <subscritores>
    <subs ref="Guicky"/>
    <subs ref="Daisy"/>
   </subscritores>
   <thumbnail link="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uMK0prafzw0/hqdefault.jpg"/>
  </lista>
 </playlist>
 <comentarios>
  <comentario id="C1" refV="Vid1" user="Guicky" data="2016-10-23">
   <text>AHAHAHAHA, bom vídeo.</text>
   <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
   <respostas>
    <texto autor="Daisy">Grande clássico!</texto>
   </respostas>
  </comentario>
  <comentario id="C2" refL="Vid2" user="Anabela65" data="2016-10-22">
   <text>Timmy timmy timmy turner...</text>
   <gosto gostou="Guicky"/>
   <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
   <respostas>
    <texto autor="Guicky">U know it.</texto>
    <resposta autor="Daisy">LOL!</resposta>
   </respostas>
  </comentario>
 </comentarios>
</xml_tube>
```

And this is my XSLT code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
  indent="yes" />
 <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />
<!--  <xsl:imports href="1.xsl"/> -->
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>2.</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//videos_pub"/>
    <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="//comentarios"/> -->
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
 
 
 <xsl:template match="videos_pub">
  <xsl:call-template name="publisher">
   <xsl:with-param name="id" select="//video/@id"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:call-template name="data">
   <xsl:with-param name="id" select="//video/@id"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:call-template name="comment">
   <xsl:with-param name="id" select="//video/@id"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 
 <xsl:template name="publisher">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <p>
   <xsl:value-of select="//video[@id = $id]/./@publisher"/>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template name="data">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <p>
   <xsl:value-of select="//video[@id= $id]/./@data"/>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template name="comment">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <p>
   <xsl:value-of select="count(//comentario[@refV = $id])" />
  </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's returning this:

> Daisy
>   2016-02-29
>   0

This is what I expected it to output:

> Daisy
>       2016-02-29
>       1

But it isn't returning the one. Why?
Do I have to exit the template `//videos_pub`?
If so, how do I do it?

Comment: You `count` command is looking for an attribute called `refVid`, but you `comentario` elements have attributes of either `refV` or `refL`, so it is not going to find anything. Can you confirm your XML is definitely correct, and it is not just a typo in your question? Thanks!

Comment: just checked, I had that typo with the `refVid`, I fixed it now, now it returns 0 instead of one.

Comment: nevermind, all fine now. i guess i just needed an extra par of eyes :P

Answer (score 0):

I realized by doing the :

```
<xsl:with-param name="id" select="//video/@id"/>
```

I was selecting the node itself not the value of the `"//video/@id"` expression.

I fixed it by doing this:

```
<xsl:with-param name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="//video/@id"/>
</xsl:with-param>
```

Now my `param`has the value of the node `//video/@id`.

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: You could also do `<xsl:with-param name="id" select="string(//video/@id)"/>` to make it a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You are overusing the `//` syntax, which is a "brute force" way of using XPath when you're not sure of a better way. You're also using "going around your elbow to get to your ***" expressions like `//video[@id= $id]/./@data`.

Also, I assume you want to output info for all of the videos, not just the first one.

Here is how you would do that, without all the sloppy stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
  indent="yes" />
  <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />
  <!--  <xsl:imports href="1.xsl"/> -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>2.</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="xml_tube/videos_pub/video"/>
        </ul>
        <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="//comentarios"/> -->
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="video">
    <li>
      <xsl:call-template name="publisher">
        <xsl:with-param name="video" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="data">
        <xsl:with-param name="video" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="comment">
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="@id"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="publisher">
    <xsl:param name="video"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="$video/@publisher"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="data">
    <xsl:param name="video"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="$video/@data"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="comment">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(/xml_tube/comentarios/comentario[@refV = $id])" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And if you want to make it really efficient, you can use an `xsl:key` to help count the comments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
  indent="yes" />
  <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />
  <xsl:key name="kVideoComments" match="comentario" use="@refV" />

  <!--  <xsl:imports href="1.xsl"/> -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>2.</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="xml_tube/videos_pub/video"/>
        </ul>
        <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="//comentarios"/> -->
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="video">
    <li>
      <xsl:call-template name="publisher">
        <xsl:with-param name="video" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="data">
        <xsl:with-param name="video" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="comment">
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="@id"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="publisher">
    <xsl:param name="video"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="$video/@publisher"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="data">
    <xsl:param name="video"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="$video/@data"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="comment">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(key('kVideoComments', $id))" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both of these output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>2.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Daisy</p>
        <p>2016-02-29</p>
        <p>1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Guicky</p>
        <p>2016-02-29</p>
        <p>0</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Guicky</p>
        <p>2016-02-29</p>
        <p>0</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Anabela65</p>
        <p>2016-02-29</p>
        <p>0</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Izzie</p>
        <p>2017-01-13</p>
        <p>0</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```